# combine key value as a new value for another map with duplicates in java

Tags: java, hashmap, key, multimap

i am having `map1` as `<k1,v1>` and i have to create `map2` with `map1` as a value like `map2=<k3,map1>`.

But keys `k1` ans `k3` are having duplicate and we have to retain duplictes.

*Example*:

```
map1={(1,a),(1,b),(2,c)}
map2={5={1,a},5={1,b},6={2,c}}
```

How to achieve this using `hashmaps` or `maps`(without using guava's multimap concept)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `HashMap` doesn't allow to store duplicate keys, you might want to consider changing your code a bit and create `HashMap<Key,ArrayList<HashMap>>`. `Map`s with the same key would be stored under the same `Key` in the `ArrayList` of your `HashMap`s. "`ArrayList` of `HashMap`s" would be the **value** of *parent* `HashMap`. There is a simple example how I see you could achieve something similar to containing more values to duplicate keys (I used hardcoded key values to make it a bit simpler to read, I also added some explanations in the comments to the code):

```
import java.util.*;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, ArrayList<Character>> map1 = new HashMap<>(); // Map containing few Characters under one key
        map1.put(1, new ArrayList<Character>()); 
        map1.get(1).add('a');
        map1.get(1).add('b');
        map1.put(2, new ArrayList<Character>());
        map1.get(2).add('c');
        System.out.println("map1: " + map1); // prints: map1: {1=[a, b], 2=[c]}
        Map<Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Character>>> map2 = new HashMap<>(); // Map storing as keys 5 and 6, values are maps from map1
        map2.put(5, new ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Character>>());
        map2.put(6, new ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Character>>());
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Character>> entry : map1.entrySet()) { // For each Integer-ArrayList pair from map1...
            if(entry.getKey().equals(1)) { // Check if key Integer is equal to 1, if it is...
                for(Character character : entry.getValue()) { // Create Maps containg pairs of Integer as key and each Character as value...
                    HashMap<Integer, Character> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
                    innerMap.put(entry.getKey(), character);
                    map2.get(5).add((new HashMap<Integer,Character>(innerMap)));
                }
            }
            if(entry.getKey().equals(2)) { // Check if key Integer is equal to 1, if it is...
                for(Character character : entry.getValue()) { // Create Maps containg pairs of Integer as key and each Character as value...
                    HashMap<Integer, Character> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
                    innerMap.put(entry.getKey(), character);
                    map2.get(6).add((new HashMap<Integer,Character>(innerMap)));
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println("map2: " + map2); // prints: map2: {5=[{1=a}, {1=b}], 6=[{2=c}]}
    }
}
```

Output you get:

```
map1: {1=[a, b], 2=[c]}
map2: {5=[{1=a}, {1=b}], 6=[{2=c}]}
```

You can use result Map and combination of `getKey()` and `getValue()` methods to create `Map`s like `5={1,a}` and `5=[{1=b}` on-the-go (but be aware that you cannot store them in the same `Map`).

Comment: Thanks for your idea. But how can i map same Key in the ArrayList of my  HashMap. could you help me on that. (as i am beginner i got stuck on this)..

Comment: @D__p Taking your example into consideration (map2): key would be 5 and you would have two HashMaps in ArrayList: {1,a} and {1,b}. There is no problem with containing two HashMaps with the same key in this ArrayList.

Comment: when i map it will get overwrite with the latest key and value. but i need to retain duplicates. in map1 (1,a) and (1,b) is there. when i tried to put it in map it will store (1,b) only. i need to get duplicates also. map1 will be given as a value to map2.

Comment: It won't, ArrayList doesn't care about duplicates. You check if  outer HashMap contains specific key (5 in your example) with "if(outerHashMap.containsKey(5))" and if it does, then ArrayList listWithKeyEqualToFive = outerHashMap.getValue(5); inner.add(new HashMap(1,b));

Comment: yeah. but coming to map1 you suggested to put <k,v> in hashmap and the convert it to ArrayList right?? when i give map.put(1,a);map.put(1,b);map.put(2,c); i will gwt only (1,b) and (1,c) i have to get (1,a) also. if i tried to add it in array list it will have only two values (1,b) and (1,c). but i need (1,a),(1,b) and (1,c)..

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand something - please  tell me what do keys 5 and 6 represent in mao2

Comment: keys 5 and 6 are keys for map2 . map1 have duplicate keys and vaues. i have to retain duplicates also. coming to map2 the key for map2 also have duplicate numbers and value for map2 will be map1( which means map1 will be given as a value to map2)

Comment: HashMap **can't** have duplicate keys. Is there a possibility to store more maps under one key or aren't you allowed to store these maps in ArrayList? This would mean that for one key you could choose which Map you want (for key 5, you could have few Maps and you could choose if you want (1,a) or (1,b)).

Comment: Thanks for your help  Przemysław Moskali.. it works for above condition. i acme across another constraint.. when i have three columns full of strings how to achieve this. Example
S.no  Ap.no  Sub
1       121        xxx
1       123         yyz
2       121         sdf    now i have to get output as 1={121,xxx},1={123,yyz},2={121,sdf} .. how could i achieve this??

Comment: @D__p I don't think you should expect someone will write code for you. As now you have some examples how  to deal with Maps, you should try to find your own way to achieve it. It is the only way to improve your skills in programming. I suggest looking into Java API Documentation, here is a list of all methods supported by Strings or Maps, it might be really helpful for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maps don't allow more than one mapping for any given key.

What you can do, though, is to have a `Map<K1, List<V1>>` for `map1`, which maps keys to lists of values.

To add an entry, instead of using `Map.put`, use [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-):

```
map1.computeIfAbsent(1, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add("a");
map1.computeIfAbsent(1, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add("b");
map1.computeIfAbsent(2, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add("c");
```

This has the following structure:

```
map1: {1=[a, b], 2=[c]}
```

Now, for `map2`, it's not clear if you'd need to take the same approach or if you'd be done using `Map.put`.